# Adicionar Objeto filho ao pai sem salvar no banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Estou criando um sistema de login que vai funcionar por meio de autenticação com papéis, tenho dois papéis já criados no meu Banco, um chamado "Cliente" e outro chamado "Administrador". A minha ideia é: Quando um novo usuário se registrar automaticamente será atribuído a ele o objeto papel "Cliente", podendo ser alterado para "Aministrador" depois, caso queira. Mas quando adiciono o objeto Papel ao objeto Usuario aparece o seguinte erro:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: br.com.projectsmanagement.entities.Paper;

Tentei resolver esse erro colocando o cascadeType = ALL ou PERSIST e salvando também por salvar o papel por meio do método save no JPA. Mas ele cria um novo valor "Cliente" no meu banco, e não é isso que eu quero. O que eu quero é pegar o valor "Cliente" na tabela de papéis e atribuir esse valor a quantos usuários eu quiser, sem criar um novo.

Por favor, peço que me ajudem.

Segue os meus códigos:

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Email
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateRegister;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private List<Project> projects;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_paper", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "paper_id"))
    private Set<Paper> papers = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, @Email String email, String password, Date dateRegister, List<Project> projects,
            Set<Paper> papers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.dateRegister = dateRegister;
        this.projects = projects;
        this.papers = papers;
    }

    //getter e setters

    public Set<Paper> getPapers() {
        return papers;
    }

    public void addPaper(Paper papers) {
        this.papers.add(papers);
    }

    public void removePaper(Paper papers) {
        this.papers.remove(papers);
    }
}
```

Paper

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_papers")
public class Paper {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Paper() {
    }

    public Paper(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //getters e setters
```

Método salvar usuário no Service

```
@Override
    public User registerUser(User user) {
        Paper paper = paperRepository.findPaperByName("Cliente");
        try {
            if (userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) == null) {
                user.setDateRegister(new Date());
                user.addPaper(paper);
                user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
                return userRepository.save(user);
            }

            return user;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new EmailExistException("Esse e-mail já está cadastrado!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver, no método salvar usuário no Service, eu troquei o **Paper paper = paperRepository.findPaperByName("Cliente");** por Paper paper = **paperRepository.findById(1L).get();**.

Dessa forma, ele pega o primeiro elemento da minha tabela papers pelo Id ao invés do nome e não cria um novo elemento "Cliente" como estava acontecendo antes.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).